# RewriteCond don't understand how to apply!

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

I still don't understand how to apply RewriteCond, due to [L] issues in .htaccess. Help!and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent reference question on serverfault, which explains how rules and conditions interact:
[Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Link as advised by current discussion on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’re looking for something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond $0 !=article.php
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Another solution would be to exclude `article.php` with the pattern of the second `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule !^article\.php$ index.php
```

But note that this will rewrite *any* other request (including other existing files). To conquer that you could use a different condition for the second rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```